# Can I use GnuPG to verify that a file is unmodified and comes from the correct sender?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, digital-signature

Can I use GnuPG to verify that a file is unmodified and comes from the correct sender?

Let's take a simple use case:

1. I have this file with some important content, let's say it is in a .tar.gz file.
2. I sign this file with something like GnuPG
3. I send this file to another guy.
4. The other guy likes to know that the file is not modified by a man in the middle, and that I was the sender. So he uses the same tool to verify that the file is ok.

Can a tool like GnuPG help out here?

Note: The two computers are Linux based, and command line is nice :)

/Thanks

---

This is what I did.

Install:

```
sudo aptitude install gnupg
```

Generate a key and export it:

```
gpg --gen-key 
gpg --export -a "Johan Simonsson" > public.key
```

Gave the other guy the public.key on a usb-stick

Created a test file to play with and signed it:

```
tar -cvzf test.tar.gz ~/.vim
gpg --output test.sig --detach-sig test.tar.gz
tar -cvzf file.tar.gz test.sig test.tar.gz
```

The other guy imports the key that I gave him on a usb-stick.

```
gpg --import public.key
```

Then I email file.tar.gz to the other guy, and he can verify the files I send to him with something like this:

```
tar -xvzf file.tar.gz
gpg --verify test.sig test.tar.gz
```

And this seems like a ok solution (since the keys are not all over the place)

---

Note: Or we can use the PGP servers to store the keys, but that is another topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Use GPG's detached signature feature.  It will create a separate file containing the signature and the file can be verified using that signature.

To sign:

```
gpg --output yourfile.sig --detach-sig yourfile.tgz
```

To Verify:

```
gpg --verify yourfile.sig yourfile.tgz
```

Comment: Looks like a good start, but when I send the .sig and the .tgz to the other PC. I get a "gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found" so I guess that I need to send him a public key to start with?

Comment: Yes, that is how GPG works.  You share your public key with others (you can put it on a keyserver if you like) and other people share their public key with you.

Comment: There seems to be a possibility to export and import keys as well, and if you send that key via another medium like in a usb-key in paper mail that would probably be ok as well. (If you don't have any ok keys in a server)